# Join a list of object's properties into a String

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning lambda right now, and I wonder how can I write this code by a single line with lambda.

I have a `Person` class which includes an `ID` and `name` fields

Currently, I have a `List<Person>` which stores these `Person` objects. What I want to accomplish is to get a string consisting of person's id just like.

**"id1,id2,id3"**.

How can I accomplish this with lambda?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To retrieve a `String` consisting of all the ID's separated by the delimiter `","` you first have to [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) the `Person` ID's into a new stream which you can then apply [`Collectors.joining`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) on.

```
String result = personList.stream().map(Person::getId)
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

if your ID field is not a `String` but rather an `int` or some other primitive numeric type then you should use the solution below:

```
String result = personList.stream().map(p -> String.valueOf(p.getId()))
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Or `.map(Person::getId).map(String::valueOf)`

Answer (score 5):

stream to map, and collect to list!

```
List<String> myListofPersons = personList.stream()
          .map(Person::getId)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you need that in a String object then join the list

```
String res = String.join(" , ", myListStringId);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: The result is List, But what I want is a string

Answer (score 2):

You can also using [Collectors#mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) as below:

```
String ids = personList.stream().collect(mapping(Person::getId
      , Collectors.joining(",")));
```

**OR**  `Person.ID` is not an instance of  `CharSequence` then  you need double mapping as below:

```
String ids = personList.stream().collect(mapping(Person::getId
    , mapping(String::valueOf
        , Collectors.joining(","))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly over-engineered, but helpful to have if this issue occurs more often (especially if you add overloaded methods that delegate to this one using default mappers and separators):

```
/**
 * @param separator used to join the values. NOTE: the separator is interpreted as a regular expression.
 * @return a list of the values' string representation according to <code>mapper</code>, separated by the specified
 *         string. Null if list is null or empty.
 */
public static <R> String toListString(Collection<R> list, String separator,
                                      Function<? super R, ? extends String> mapper)
{
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
    {
        return null;
    }

    return list.stream()
               .map(mapper)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(separator));
}
```

and the appropriate inverse funtion:

```
/**
 * @param list a list of values, separated by the specified separator
 * @param separator used to join the values. NOTE: the separator is interpreted as a regular expression.
 * @param mapper the function to map a single string to a value.
 * @return a list of the values. Empty if string is null or empty.
 */
public static <R> List<R> fromListString(String list, String separator,
                                         Function<? super String, ? extends R> mapper)
{
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
    {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    return Arrays.stream(list.trim().split(separator))
                 .map(mapper)
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

If performance is an issue I would opt for the classic loop approach:

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for(R r : list){
        if (s.length() != 0)
            s.append(separator);
        s.append(mapper.apply(r));
    }
    return s.toString();
```

and:

```
    List<R> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : list.trim().split(separator)){
        result.add(mapper.apply(s));
    }
    return result;
```