# Why Stream operations is duplicated with Collectors?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Please allow me to make some complaints, maybe it is boringly but I want to describe:"**Why did this question will be raised?**".
I have answered questions is different from others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245790/join-a-list-of-objects-properties-into-a-string/44251192#44251192), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247260/including-elements-from-unmodified-lists-in-modified-lists-in-a-2d-list-with-str/44249062#44249062) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242103/how-to-reuse-application-of-filter-map-on-a-stream/44245460#44245460) last night.

After I get dig into it, I found there are many duplicated logic between [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) that violates [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, e.g: [Stream#map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) & [Collectors#mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), [Stream#filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) & [Collectors#filtering](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) in jdk-9 and .etc.

But it seems to reasonable since [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) abide by [Tell, Don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle/[Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) abide by [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle.

I can only think of a few reasons why [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) operations is duplicated with [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)s as below:

1. We don't care of how the [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is created in a big context. in this case [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) operation is more effectively and faster than [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) since it can mapping a [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to another [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) simply, for example:

   ```
   consuming(stream.map(...));
   consuming(stream.collect(mapping(...,toList())).stream());

   void consuming(Stream<?> stream){...}
   ```
2. [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) is more powerful that can composes [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)s together to collecting elements in a stream, However, [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) only providing some useful/highly used operations. for example:

   ```
   stream.collect(groupingBy(
     ..., mapping(
           ..., collectingAndThen(reducing(...), ...)
          )
   ));
   ```
3. [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) operations is more expressiveness than [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) when doing some simpler working, but they are more slower than [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)s since it will creates a new stream for each operation and [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is more heavier and abstract than [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html). for example:

   ```
   stream.map(...).collect(collector);
   stream.collect(mapping(..., collector));
   ```
4. [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) can't applying short-circuiting terminal operation as [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). for example:

   ```
   stream.filter(...).findFirst();
   ```

Does anyone can come up with other disadvantage/advantage why Stream operations is duplicated with Collectors here? I'd like to re-understand them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. If you have a complaint, submit a bug report or a request for enhancement, or hire a hall.

Comment: See also [Collectors.summingInt() vs mapToInt().sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023822/2711488)

Comment: @Holger thanks for the link, I cost most of time to understand answer of yours since I'm not good at english.

Comment: @EJP sir, maybe you misunderstand me. what I have said is I want to clarify why this question is raised. complaints is not gripe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chaining a dedicated terminal stream operation might be considered more expressive by those being used to chained method calls rather than the “LISP style” of composed collector factory calls. But it also allows optimized execution strategies for the stream implementation, as it knows the actual operation instead of just seeing a `Collector` abstraction.

On the other hand, as you named it yourself, `Collector`s can be composed, allowing to perform these operation embedded in another collector, at places where stream operations are not possible anymore. I suppose, this mirroring become apparent only at a late stage of the Java 8 development, which is the reason why some operations lacked their counterpart, like `filtering` or `flatMapping`, which will be there only in Java 9. So, having two different APIs doing similar things, was not a design decision made at the start of the development.

Comment: I never said that the “LISP style” was unreasonable. All I said, is, that Java developers are more used to the chained invocation style.

Comment: @Holger if you are right then this makes perfect sense, considering how late java-8 was at that time...

Comment: I don't think jdk will includes all operations in `Stream` as `Collector`s since it will makes `Stream` ugly and its responsibility is unclear.

Comment: Collectors are not meant to supersede stream operations. But with Java 9, all stateless intermediate operations will be available as collector, `mapping​`, `flatMapping​`, `filtering​`, (and `collectingAndThen`, if you want to count that). Likewise, almost all non-short-circuiting operation have a counterpart, `maxBy`, `minBy`, `reducing`, `counting`. What’s left, are short-circuiting operations and `forEach` and `toArray`, which work fundamentally different to collectors.

Answer (score 7):

The `Collectors` methods that seem to duplicate `Stream` methods are offering additional functionality. They make sense when used in combination with other `Collector`s.

For example, if we consider `Collectors.mapping()`, the most common use is to pass it to a `Collectors.groupingBy` `Collector`.

Consider this example (taken from the Javadoc):

```
List<Person> people = ...
Map<City, Set<String>> namesByCity
         = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getCity, TreeMap::new,
                                              mapping(Person::getLastName, toSet())));
```

`mapping` is used here to transform the element type of the value `Collection` of each group from `Person` to `String`.

Without it (and the `toSet()` `Collector`) the output would be `Map<City, List<Person>>`.

Now, you can certainly `map` a `Stream<Person>` to a `Stream<String>` using `people.stream().map(Person::getLastName)`, but then you will lose the ability to group these last names by some other property of `Person` (`Person::getCity` in this example).

Comment: sir, thanks very much. I found I have described it in the second in my question. but mine is too broad.