# using java Stream to get a sum, average, and sort

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am studying java Stream and having hard time solving questions below. The reason why I got stuck is because I have no idea about dealing with `Stream<Integer>`.

I stumbled upon a solution of "count" by doing `list.stream().count()`, but other than this, I can't proceed further. Please help me how to deal with these problems and tell me why `list.stream().count()` works in this situation. So far, I've tried everything I've learned.

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer>list = Arrays.asList(5,3,4,1,2);
        System.out.println("sum by using Stream : " + sum);
        System.out.println("count by using Stream: " + count);
        System.out.println("average by using Stream : " + avg);
        System.out.println("sort by using Stream");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it me or is your code here incomplete ? How is `sum`, `count` and `avg` being initialized?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Streams API? It tells you what methods exist. And there are lots, lots of informations at the Oracle site.

Comment: Also [`.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) from a streamable gives you the _number_  of elements in that stream.

Comment: it is incomplete, so i need lines of code to work out those system.out.println() and i don`t know how to get the sum, avg, and sort.

Comment: Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html   the example even shows sample code of a sum.

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem, can you [accept one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as the correct solution? (and upvote on the useful ones)

Answer (score 36):

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .summaryStatistics();

stats.getSum();
stats.getCount();
stats.getAverage();
```

For the sorted, you will have to stream again.

Comment: or `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4) .stream() .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));`

Comment: @Holger Is there a way to know when to choose one implementation or the other? I mean, many times, there are operations that can be done either with stream intermediate operations or with collectors, i.e. `Stream.map` vs `Collectors.mapping`, reducing, fitlering, flatmapping and summarizing, etc

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner for this specific case, it doesn’t matter and the choice is yours. It’s worth knowing both, as it may make a difference when you want to extend the code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37025002/2711488) for details. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44259061/2711488).

Comment: @Eugene The IntSummaryStatistics idea was a recent memory finally :)

Answer (score 13):

The reason of why `list.stream().count()` works but `list.stream().sum()` doesn't is because `list.stream()` returns a [`Stream<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and there is a [`Stream::count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) method, but there isn't a `Stream::sum` or `Stream::average`.

To get the sum and avg first you have to map each integer value in the `Stream<Integer>` that you get when you do `list.stream()` to an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). This is the int primitive specialization of Stream. This can be done using the [`Stream::mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
```

Doing this you can use the methods [`IntStream::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) and [`IntStream::average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--):

```
System.out.println("sum by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
System.out.println("average by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average());
```

Or even better, you can use the [`IntStream::summaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) to get the sum, count and avg together (also the min and the max value):

```
System.out.println("sum, count, avg, min and max using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics());
```

To sort the values you can use the [`Stream::sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) method:

```
System.out.println("sort by using Stream: " + list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) is a good post that can help you to understand how to use the Java 8 Stream Api.

Answer (score 4):

You can do just like this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,3,4,1,2);
        System.out.println("sum by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
        System.out .println("count by using Stream: " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).count());
        System.out.println("average by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average());
        System.out.println("sort by using Stream: " + list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mapToInt` or `mapToDouble`

and you can print list by `forEach(System.out::println)`

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,3,4,1,2);

System.out.println("sum by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());

System.out .println("count by using Stream: " + list.stream().count());

System.out.println("average by using Stream : " + list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average());

System.out.println("sort by using Stream: " );

list.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```