# How to call a method on a array of a class in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm a begginer doing some exercises on Java OOP so here's my problem.
I have a `Book` class with this attribute:

`private Author[] authors;`

I need a method that returns just the names of those authors(name1,name2,..). The `Authors` class has a `getName()` method:

```
public String getName() {
        return name;
}
```

And I tried following code but it doesn't work !

```
//Method in the Book class
public String getAuthorsNames(){
    return authors.getName();
}
```

Do I need to loop through the array or is there another way ?

Comment: Do you want to return a `String[]` or a single `String`? And if you really want a single `String` as your code suggests, what should it look like?

Comment: If you've got multiple authors, then there are multiple names. What single string do you expect to return?

Comment: @Thomas just a single `String` of the names separated by a comma eg. "name1,name2,name3"

Comment: authors is not a class.  It is an array of Author.  Yes, you need to loop through the array or use a stream.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i'm not familiar with what a stream is yet, can you give me an example?

Comment: Like this: [Join a list of object's properties into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245790/join-a-list-of-objects-properties-into-a-string) but [creating the stream from the array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888429/how-can-i-create-a-stream-from-an-array)

Comment: While it's not exactly a beginner concept, a stream in this case would be `Stream.of(this.authors).map(Author::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private Author[] authors;` is array of object Author

you need to add the index then get the name, here is an example:

```
class Author {

  private String name;

  public Author(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
```

and in your class Book:

```
  class Book {
    private Author[] authors;
    public Book(int authorsSize) {
      authors = new Author[authorsSize];
    }
    
    public void setAuthor(int index) {
      this.authors[index] = new Author("Author Name"):
    }

   public String getAuthorName(int index) {
      return this.authors[index].getName();
   }

   public String getAllAuthors() {
     String all = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
         all += authors[i].getName() + ", ";
     }
     
     return all;
   }

  }
```

After adding Authors .. use getAllAuthors

--- more ---
Instead of `Author[] authors = new Authors[size];`
You can use `ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();`
then you can use:

```
authors.add(new Author("Author name1"));
authors.add(new Author("Author name2"));
authors.add(new Author("Author name3"));
authors.add(new Author("Author name4"));
......
```

Comment: That's not what he asked - " the names separated by a comma eg. "name1,name2,name3""

Comment: updated the answer man .. its just an idea and then he can solve the rest .. sometimes we need to think ..

Comment: Some good advice here, but the repeated `String` concatenation is an anti-pattern. Use `StringBuilder` instead.